# Spring - Autowire fails when adding an aspect-backed annotation to overridden method

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I have an authentication service implementing org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService and defined as:

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService {
    // Autowires ..

    @Override
    //@Logged(successMessage = "User %s logged in")
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) { .. }
}
```

It is autowired into an extension of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and used to configure authentication:

```
// Annotations ...
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService(authService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }
    // Other security config stuff ...
}
```

And last, I have created a custom annotation called @Logged, that is picked up by an aspect that applies around advice to the annotated method and performs some logging logic. Lets just say that if you pass only one argument to it, it will log successful returns.

Applying the @Logged annotation to the overriden AuthService.loadUserByUsername method causes the application to crash on startup, displaying the message about not being able to autowire AuthService into the SecurityConfig. Everything works flawlessly if I don't put the annotation to that overriden method - authentication works (complete with autowiring) and logging annotation works in other parts of the system.

## Question

Why is this happening and can it be fixed?

I would really like to log that exact method using my fancy logging anotation.
Thanks :)

### Technical details

Spring 4 with Boot, Jetty 9

Stack trace (part of):

2014-09-22 12:41:05 WARN  AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$InitializerListener@8bb473: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bluepixelflag.services.AuthService com.bluepixelflag.config.SecurityConfig.authService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.bluepixelflag.services.AuthService field com.bluepixelflag.config.SecurityConfig.authService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is using a proxy to add aspects to `AuthService`. Without the annotation it would just use a simple class.

Change

`private AuthService authService;`

to

`private UserDetailsService authService;`

and it ought to work. Or, use cglib proxies instead of JDK dynamic proxies.

Aside: the point of using aspects for logging is to try to avoid one line of code per logging call. If you use an aspect annotation for every method call you want logged, you haven't saved any complexity (in fact you've increased it), and might as well just call a logger in code.

Comment: Thank you for your working solution! I thought that all @Service annotated classes were proxied by default - I'd be grateful if you could further clarify what I've missed. About logging - while i agree that aspect-based logging trades lines one-for-one (my homegrown aspect supports multiple exceptions, each with it's own message), the need to introduce large try-catch blocks only to log a message clutters the code a lot imho. Plus, i needed to learn AOP and logging was the perfect domain to explore :) Thanks again for your help and time!

Comment: @hoodieman I take it back - if your aspect does try/catch too, then it's better than a plain method call. Personally, I prefer a single fault barrier (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effective-exceptions-092345.html) to ensure uncaught exceptions are logged exactly once, but your solution sounds good too.